# Template class typedef - use outside of class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I have a class like this:

```
struct WorkItemResultData;

template <typename ExecutionPolicy>
class Engine
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<WorkItemResultData> WorkItemResultData_ptr;
}
```

`typedef` does not depend on any template argument. Is there a way to use type `Engine::WorkItemResultData_ptr` outside of `Engine` class ?

*EDIT* I know I could use it like awoodland proposed the solution bellow but my typedef is independent of type arguments and want to be able to do it without specifying a specific Engine type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use type `Engine::WorkItemResultData_ptr` outside of Engine class ?

Yes, but you'll need to say `typename` if it's in a template context, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
  typename Engine<T>::WorkItemResultData_ptr instance;
}
```

You can't access that `typedef` without a type. There are three workarounds possible though:

1. `typedef` outside the template! - it's likely it doesn't have much to do with the template if it doesn't depend on the types.
2. Use a bodge and refer to `Engine<void>::WorkItemResultData_ptr`.
3. Have a non-template base class which contains the typedef and inherit from that. You can access the non-template base class fine then.

Comment: I don't want to specify typename though :-). I am not in a template context.

Comment: I am in a context where I don't know/want to know Engine template type.

Comment: @Ghita if it's in a template you *have* to specify a type of some sort though. If you know it doesn't matter what that type is you can always pass `void` as the type.

Comment: You are right. Engine was before a non-template class and and that time it maked more sense to have that typedef inside the type but now as Engine is a template class typedef outside of the template class makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Since the typedef does not depend on `Engine` at all, you can pull it out of the class:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<WorkItemResultData> WorkItemResultData_ptr;

template <typename ExecutionPolicy>
class Engine {...};
```

If you want to keep it encapsulated, simply use a namespace:

```
namespace Engine
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<WorkItemResultData> WorkItemResultData_ptr;
}
```